# How to insert relational data in Access database using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I have two relational tables: the `Profiles` table which contains 3 kinds of user roles (Manager, Developer, Common User) and the `Users` table which contains information about the user and their roles ID (Profile_ID field) in the `Access 2010` database.

I created a Webform in `ASP.NET` which should simply register users, asking for their names, selecting their roles in a dropdown list and inserting it all in the Access database. As in the following code:

```
Dim cs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Access 2010").ConnectionString
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (nome, Profile_ID) VALUES ('" & Me.txtNome.Text & "', " & Me.ddRoles.SelectedIndex & ")"
        .Connection = cn
        .Connection.Open()
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
        .Connection.Close()
        .Dispose()
    End With
    cn.Dispose()
```

It happens that I can't insert in the database because they have a relationship between each other, it gives me an error. Actually, I just need to insert data in the `Users` table 'cause the roles are fixed. How can I do it?

### EDIT

The error I get is `You can not add or change records, it is necessary that they have a related record in table 'Profiles'.`

Comment: You can not add or change records, it is necessary that they have a related record in table 'Profiles'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your command text to take the **SelectedValue** of the dropdown instead of the selected index.

```
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (nome, Profile_ID) VALUES ('" & Me.txtNome.Text & "', " & Me.ddRoles.SelectedValue & ")"
```

If that doesn't work you need to make sure that the drop down is being bound properly to the Role name/id.

Comment: It worked now.. but it's creating only records with one profile (the Common User profile which has the ID number 5, to be exact). Although the HTML seems right: Common User assigned to value 5, Developer assigned as value 6 and Manager assigned as value 7

Comment: here is my code which populates the dropdownlist and tries to insert into the database: http://pastebin.com/a2XbqaAY

Comment: are you binding the drop down on page load every time? If so you'll lose the selected value each time you re-databind it.

Answer (score 0):

insert into tablename(papercode,paper type,semster,dato)values('" & textbox1.text & "', '" & dropdownlist1.text &"')